# Expecting Member Declaration kotlin androd studio

Tags: android, kotlin

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }
    val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.mybutton)
    btn.text = 'click me'
}
```

it wont run it errors saying expecting member declaration its running android 5.0 as min sdk

I'm trying to change the button text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put some of your code outside the `onCreateMethod`. You need to move the closing bracket after all your code like this:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
        val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.mybutton)
        btn.text = 'click me'
    } // <----
}
```